How to smooth rsi from HTF - pinescript
I was invited to indicator that has waves momentum (the same as market cipher blues waves) based on higher timeframe. They are smoothed but plotted even on unclosed bar. How to obtain the same effect? Below i have the same wave but not smoothed. If i use gaps=barmerge.gaps_on when requesting higher timeframe i would lost last bar from htf. If i ta.sma(myValue, x) the result wouldn't be the same. enter image description here
I tried to find answer on pinescript groups on telegram, write my code. Nothing works.
